# Maven does not deploy application / start server after first run

Tags: maven-3

I created a sample cxf service with following artifact. imported project in eclipse. Run As > maven install

It did execute compile>war> startserver> deploy war> execute test> stop server

Now after making some changes in code and test classes, when i do mvn install, it does not start/stop server, nor it deploys on tomcat. POM is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.domain.test.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Simple CXF JAX-RS webapp service using spring configuration</name>
    <description>Simple CXF JAX-RS webapp service using spring configuration</description>
    <properties>
        <jackson.version>1.8.6</jackson.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-cli</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <port>13000</port>
                                <path>/jaxrs-service</path>
                                <useSeparateTomcatClassLoader>true</useSeparateTomcatClassLoader>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.5</source>
                        <target>1.5</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectNameTemplate>[artifactId]-[version]</projectNameTemplate>
                        <wtpmanifest>true</wtpmanifest>
                        <wtpapplicationxml>true</wtpapplicationxml>
                        <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>reserve-network-port</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>reserve-network-port</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <portNames>
                                <portName>test.server.port</portName>
                            </portNames>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-tomcat</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run-war</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <port>${test.server.port}</port>
                            <path>/jaxrs-service</path>
                            <fork>true</fork>
                            <useSeparateTomcatClassLoader>true</useSeparateTomcatClassLoader>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-tomcat</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shutdown</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <path>/jaxrs-service</path>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <service.url>http://localhost:${test.server.port}/jaxrs-service</service.url>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>verify</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

got it..."Convention over Configuration...." is the issue ....Test should run in integration-test phase. for this one should name test as *IT.java :)

This fixes issue.